# Issue booting HP ProLiant Gen 8 from ODD after upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, ssd, hp-proliant

So I have a HP ProLiant Gen8 micro server with 4 disks bays. The mobo has a connection for an ODD and since I wanted to setup the drive bays for raid and boot from an SSD, I have been successfully using the ODD as the boot drive and running my OS from it until I tried this upgrade to 18.04. Now, with all other drives removed except SSD as well as having the SSD set as the logical drive and boot in BIOS, it always just keeps going after attempting to boot from "C:/" and just starts to loop on booting from NIC. I cannot figure what else to do now that this has happened. What I had noticed happened in the past on Ubuntu 16.04 is that when an update was installed via `sudo apt-get update` that may have had a kernel update in it, it woould act this way, but then after removing the other drives and resetting the logical boot drive again would resolve things back to normal. Never did go through the route of trying to find a permanent fix in `fstab` for this. At any rate, am hoping some of you could provide some answers and insight.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered booting the base operating system from the internal USB port via a low profile USB flash drive (e.g. Sandisk Cruzer)?

Performance has been very satisfactory with this set up. It is tried and tested -- both on my set up and others reporting on the internet.

Although it should be, in theory, possible to boot of the spare optical drive SATA port, I have not seen many people report success with this. Many people are booting of internal USB and this should give you most of the same functionality. Performance will be slightly worse than a dedicated SSD but, for many uses, still within satisfactory limits.

Comment: I say C, but I mean the main drive that OS is on.